# How to make button click automatic in MVC view using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have developed an MVC application and want to make my button click automatic.
In this I want my button to click daily at 10 p.m. automatically.
This is my button in my View.

```
 <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="btnAdd2" value="Add 2" />    
 </a>
```

I have googled a lot and got one such thing.

```
setInterval(click,3000);
        function click() {
            $("#btnAdd2").click();
            alert("Automatic button click after 3 seconds.");
        }
```

This is working fine but it is clicking after every 3 seconds. But I want it to click daily at 10 p.m.
If anyone has idea to resolve this please help and your help would be appreciated.....Thanks.

Comment: But what if there is no user interacting with your site at 10 p.m.? I think that this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @Steve Actually, I want it to click button in the back ground automatically...Is there a way to achieve such??

Comment: You want this to happen only if the user is active on the page at that time? Why, what is the reason for the specific timing? Anyway you'd need an interval which checks the current time, and if it's 10pm, runs the click. Where are you stuck? You can easily research how to check current time with JavaScript. P.S. This seems to have nothing directly to do with C# or asp.net

Comment: @ADyson thanks for ur reply...I have shared my jquery code above in that I am facing difficulty in setting the specific time as in SetInterval it has only miliseconds and I don't know how to initial the time to 10 pm.

Comment: setInterval just tells the job to run repeatedly. _Within_ that job you need to check the current time, and decide what to do. There's no way to trigger interval to run only at a specific time, you just need to let it repeat, and check the time of day repeatedly until you find it matches your target time.

Comment: @ADyson Ineed it because I want to update the database daily at 10 pm. So, I want the button to be click daily automatically at 10pm.....Hope you got the idea of implementing such functinality..

Comment: `I want to update the database daily at 10 pm`...if you want this to run consistently, every day, without user intervention, and always run even if no users are using the website at that time, then this would be far better implemented as a background task - e.g. using a windows service or scheduled task. Then it won't fail if the user isn't logged in, or is viewing another browser tab (which can cause scripts in the hidden tabs to stop running).

Comment: The only use case I think of for the jQuery version is if you have a display which never logs out of the website, has it displayed permanently, and you need to update the database with data which can only be found in that browser. Also, what if multiple people are on the page at 10pm? Should it run the update multiple times? It's not clear. Your requirement is very unusual.

Comment: @ADyson review my comment about the XY Problem. The asker is not telling us what is the real requirement here and they think that jquery  and setInterval is the way to solve it.

Comment: @Steve I know. I saw your comment and agree with it. That's why I'm trying to prompt them to explain (I've asked at least twice), and suggesting a common alternative (with clear description of the scenario in which it would be used) in case that causes a lightbulb moment. :-)

Comment: @Steve I have commented to ADyson about my requirement you can check that....It is clearly showing the need

Comment: Yes but the need is weird. Read what we said...are you sure it's definitely what you want? What is the reason for doing it from the browser specifically? You haven't explained that. Most people don't create scheduled tasks using jQuery. As I've mentioned, it's not very reliable or efficient. Please clarify why you think you want a browser-based version, specifically

Comment: @ADyson See the think is my requirement is to update database on daily basis and currently I am updating it manually with button click in my MVC website....So  I want to automate this functionality and Jquery is not necessary to use for me I am looking a way .....Hope this time u got the idea of my problem.

Comment: jQuery is the wrong way to approach this. It's the task of updating the DB that you want to automate, not the button click. Don't think in terms of the UI, think in terms of the task you want to accomplish. In your mind (and in your code!), separate the job itself from the user interface which triggers the job. As I mentioned earlier, this is a task you should do with a Windows service, or a Windows scheduled task which runs a separate small program to execute the database update. Then it's fully automatic and reliable and doesn't rely on a browser being open and visible in someone's screen.

Comment: As Steve said right at the start, this is an absolutely classic XY problem - asking for the presumed solution rather than describing (and researching) the underlying requirement. Did you think to research how others automate their processes? The fact you found it difficult in  the jQuery/browser environment (which is a user interface tool, not an automation tool) should perhaps have been a clue that you were barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: thanks for correcting me about my approach.....But there is problem I am updating database from my action method using SQL bulk copy and If I use windows service that how to achieve this....Please explain

Comment: Run the same code from the service. You may have to copy the code. Or you could make the windows service run a http request to trigger your action method. Use your imagination

Comment: @ADyson Ok, I will try this. Thanks for the help

Comment: Why don't you just use free services such as IFTTT, Zapier or others (scheduled http  requests)?